# how to get event coordinate with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, events

```
<a id="clickme">here</a>
```

when I click on the link,I want to get the coordinate where click happens.

how to do that with jQuery?

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position

Just add an (e) on your click callback and use e.pageX and e.pageY, I think

Answer (score 3):

This should work,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#clickme").click(function(e){
      alert(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
   }); 
});
```